# Is it possible to use UIScrollView in a UIView and not in a UIViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview

Is it possible to use UIScrollView in a UIView instead of UIViewController?

I tried to use in a UIView but, that does not work. I could not find the proper sample for my project.

I need horizontal scrolling over views that have size 90x90 pixels.

here is my code

```
    UIScrollView* scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 35, 400, 200)];
    [scrollView setScrollEnabled:YES];
    scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
    [scrollView setDelegate:self];
    scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor brownColor];
    [scrollView setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator:YES];
    [scrollView setIndicatorStyle:UIScrollViewIndicatorStyleDefault]; scrollView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    scrollView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
    [scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(630,0)];

    [self addSubview:scrollView];


    //self.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768);

    [self setBackgroundColor:[[UIColor blackColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.8]];


    circleView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100,100,90,90)];        
    circleView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor whiteColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:1];
    //circleView.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
    //circleView.layer.borderWidth = 4;

    UILabel* circleIndex = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    circleIndex.frame    = CGRectMake(30, 25, 40, 40);
    [circleIndex setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial-BoldMT" size:40]];
    [circleIndex setText:@"A"];

    [circleView addSubview:circleIndex];


    circleView2 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100+100,100,90,90)];
    circleView2.backgroundColor = [[UIColor whiteColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:1];

    circleView3 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100+100+100,100,90,90)];
    circleView3.backgroundColor = [[UIColor whiteColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:1];

    circleView4 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100+100+100+100,100,90,90)];
    circleView4.backgroundColor = [[UIColor whiteColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:1];

    circleView5 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100+100+100+100+100,100,90,90)];
    circleView5.backgroundColor = [[UIColor whiteColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:1];

    circleView6 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100+100+100+100+100+100,100,90,90)];
    circleView6.backgroundColor = [[UIColor whiteColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:1];

    [scrollView addSubview:circleView];

    [scrollView addSubview:circleView2];

    [scrollView addSubview:circleView3];

    [scrollView addSubview:circleView4];

    [scrollView addSubview:circleView5];

    [scrollView addSubview:circleView6];



    exitView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(70,-5,30,30)];
    exitView.layer.cornerRadius = 15;

    exitView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    exitView.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor];
    exitView.layer.borderWidth = 2;

    [circleView addSubview:exitView];

    UIView *exitLabel = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(8,13,15,3)];
    exitLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    exitLabel.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor];
    exitLabel.layer.borderWidth = 2;


      [exitView addSubview:exitLabel];

    UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPress =
    [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                                  action:@selector(handleLongPress:)];
    [circleView addGestureRecognizer:longPress];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *singlePress =
    [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                                  action:@selector(handleSinglePress:)];
    [exitView addGestureRecognizer:singlePress];
    //[longPress release];


    UITapGestureRecognizer *singlePress2 =
    [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                            action:@selector(singlePress:)];
    [circleView2 addGestureRecognizer:singlePress2];



    [exitView setHidden:YES];

    [circleView bringSubviewToFront:exitView];




    [exitView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];


}
return self;
}
```

Comment: Yes it is possible. Please share your code.

Comment: Kindly share your code.

Comment: `UIScrollView` is a subclass of `UIView`. Any UIView instance can be a subview of any other UIView.

Comment: i have added my code, i am not able to see scroll effect

Comment: Why does your contentSize have 0 height?

Comment: @fzwo i have fixed that but still no action

Comment: What exactly is the problem? I copied Your code in my project and I see a scrollview, with possibility to scroll horizontally and see added uiview rectangles.

Comment: @Guntis Treulands, i could not see the scroll functionality on my simulator

Comment: I pasted your code as it is and i was able to see scroll as well.
What is the frame of your view? You seem to be pasted your code on the
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame of the custom View. What is the frame you are giving to your view?

Comment: @Puneet thank you, it is about frame size

Comment: if that solved your question, please accept the answer below:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I pasted your code as it is and I was able to see scroll as well.
You seem to be pasted your code on the
`- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame`
of the custom View.
 What is the frame you are giving to your view?

Answer (score -1):

The problem i think is the content size is not defined properly

```
[scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(630,0)];
```

gives 630 in width and 0 in height means you try to implement a horizontal scroll.Try some larger content size and try to scroll the code looks good

I trried out a uiview with scrollview and it worked well

```
@implementation TestView

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        [self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];
        UIScrollView* scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 35, 600, 600)];
        [scrollView setScrollEnabled:YES];
        scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
        scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
        [scrollView setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator:YES];
        [scrollView setIndicatorStyle:UIScrollViewIndicatorStyleDefault]; scrollView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
        scrollView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
        [scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(630,0)];

        [self addSubview:scrollView];



    }
    return self;
}
```

added to VC as

```
TestView *view=[[TestView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 30, 500, 600)];

[self.view addSubview:view];
```

Comment: He mentioned that he requires only horizontal scrolling. This is not the problem.